# Working with digits in numbers in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, typecasting-operator

Say you have a number...

```
var number = 643
```

and you want to do some math on it.

For example, you'd want to take the last two digits (43) and see if an integer leaves no remainder for the the last two digits minus the last digit.

For example:

```
var remainder = 40 % 5  //'5' is the random integer, and 40 is the last two digits(43) minus the last digit(3)
```

This would be rather trivial in vbscript but somehow being a newbie in Swift 3 I cannot get this done in the playground.

If I do

```
var number = 643
var str = (String)number
let lastChar = str.characters.last
var digit = 0
digit = Int(lastChar)
```

The last line gives out a warning
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '(String.CharacterView._Element?)'

[image]

Could someone please help me out?
I was not able to find the answer using google in more than 30 minutes and normally I'm good in shorter time...

Thank you kindly

Comment: lastChar is trying to do something to var str. But var str is a string, not an int.

Comment: `(String)number` does not compile. Why not `643 % 100` to get `43`?

Comment: @vadian Why not indeed! What an elegant solution. Now I'll need to divine how to get the number of digits in a number and I should be good.

Comment: @SuperWoman What exactly is the question you're asking? You mention a lot of seemingly unrelated things. What is your input, and what is the output you want?

Comment: @SuperWoman - "Now I'll need to divine how to get the number of digits in a number" - you can use base 10 log to figure that out. (If you can't see how to do it ask another question showing what you tried and someone will undoubtedly help you out.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is easier to do with just integer manipulation:

```
let number = 643

let last2Digits = number % 100 // 43
let lastDigit = number % 10 // 3

let result = last2Digits - lastDigit //40
```